# Fix the position of label on Mouseover

Tags: javascript, css, label

I have lable and using JS i am doing label to be bold  but when label is bold is change the position of other label objects i want to be bold the label on its same position without changing or disturbing other labels
here is my JS and Label code

```
function changeCA()
    {
    document.getElementById("CA").style.border="solid 1px #464646";
    document.getElementById("CA").style.fontWeight="bold";
    document.getElementById("CA").style.color="white";
    //document.getElementById("CA").style.marginLeft="-15px"; 
    //document.getElementById("CA").style.paddingRight="-5px"; 

    document.getElementById("CA").style.borderTopColor="#dd4b39";
    document.getElementById("CA").style.borderLeftColor="#464646";
    document.getElementById("CA").style.borderRightColor="#464646";
    document.getElementById("CA").style.borderBottomColor="#464646";
    }

<asp:Label ID="CA" runat="server"   Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="10pt" ForeColor="#CCCCCC"   Text="Current Activities" Style="padding-top:4px; padding-bottom:4px; margin:0px 1px 0 0;"          onmouseover="ChangeCA()"></asp:Label>
```

Anyone please help me that how to  fix the position whenit becomes the bold

Comment: FYI, your code would be a lot cleaner if you in just added a class the the CA object and then put all those styles in a CSS file for that class.  The body of the function could be one line.  You also don't need to set all four border colors.  You can a simplified example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ERgVE/.

Answer (score 0):

Set a fixed width for the label. This also means you need to set the display of the label to block or inline-block.